# How to prevent users seeing target links in web application with adsense?

Tags: javascript, http, url-rewriting, redirect, adsense

I would like to make a web application with adsense (or similar) and the following are my assumptions:

- each web page (with unique text) needs to have unique static URL (e.g., /page1) in order to be able to index it for adsense
- users navigate to other pages by clicking on links (there are multiple links that will send users to pages based on their behavior)
- I would like to redirect users based on their history etc. at the server side, but in theory it would be possible to precompute each page to contain the correct links (i.e., to the intended target page based on the user response/click) directly
- I do not want users to see to which page they are going (it would not work if they would see that by clicking on this link they would go to /page2, not to /page3, for this application it is important to not be able to guess the next step)

How to achieve this? If some of my assumptions are incorrect, feel free to challenge them.

Some solutions:

1. Redirect at the server side - i.e., the link will be resolved at server side, leading to redirect on each request (this is what I don't like here). Otherwise this would be very clean - the server would just get user's click and do the rest.
2. Put in the target links and hide them somehow from the user, so that he is not able to see whether the link goes to /page2 or /page3, i.e., solve this at client side. How can I do that in the best way? Perhaps using javascript for hiding the target URL or for reacting on each click, but here I don't like so much dependency on javascript.

Do you see any solutions for this? I don't need detailed code, just the direction to go, I am able to write javascript or to add redirect rules.

I just need to not let users see what will be the next steps based on their response/click and at the same time I think I need to preserve static URLs for adsense. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion it's on page load make an ajax call to get the links from server and then, when user clicks on link change location using window.location.assign() into an iframe.